# Rails - Methods on Large Arrays (performance)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I'm trying to perform `sort` and `uniq` methods on large arrays of Active Record objects in the console - for example, trying to sort 1M records by certain attributes, etc.

I'm finding that it is extremely slow - how can I increase speed here?

Quick example: I have an an array of AR "item" objects (900,000 of them). I want to perform the `uniq!` them by 2 attributes - name and brand.

Thanks!

Comment: You *need* to perform these sorts/filters in the database. There is no way to make this performant in Ruby after your records have been converted to 1 million ActiveRecord objects.

Comment: ok - the reason I did not perform validations at the db level was because I was doing mass inserts with `connection_execute`. So, the only way is to validate before inserting in to the db?

Comment: What is the source of the 900k items?  Maybe you can first insert them into a temp table and then pull out the unique records and move to your final destination.

Comment: Querying from Facebook en masse - for lots of users.

Comment: if you query the data from facebook, store the array of unique fields as a key to a hash. if the key already exists, you will have a match. you could use a list as a value and append the matches. that is extremely fast.